I want to reset the position of the Group Output node of a Composite
Reset the position of the Group Output node of the material that has been moved to its initial position.
Then calculate the difference between the current position and the reset position
And then calculate the difference between the current position and the reset position.
However, in the following script, all nodes except the Composite node did not move.
Can someone please tell me how to do this?
import bpy

# Check if a Compositing nodetree is being used in Blender
if bpy.context.scene.node_tree:
    node_tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree
    
    # Get the current location of the Composite node
    composite_node = None
    for node in node_tree.nodes:
        if node.type == 'COMPOSITE':
            composite_node = node
            break
    
    if composite_node:
        # Move the Composite node to (300, 400)
        composite_node.location = (300, 400)
        
        # Calculate the difference between the current position and the initial position
        original_location = composite_node.location.copy()
        diff_x = 300 - original_location.x
        diff_y = 400 - original_location.y
        
        # Get the current position of all other nodes
        for node in node_tree.nodes:
            # Exclude the Composite node as it has already been moved
            if node != composite_node:
                # Move the node by adding the calculated difference to its position
                node.location.x += diff_x
                node.location.y += diff_y


Hello. It seems the order of your statements needs to change, because diff_x and diff_y are both always equal to 0 in your script. I would set original_location  before moving the composite node. Of course this looks awfully like a GPT-generated script so you can just copy-paste my comment in the discussion. ;)
